# Need advice (hint) or help create 2 string function

Tags: c, insert, c-strings, function-definition

The function receives two strings `str1` and `str2` and returns an integer. The function will insert the `str2` string at the beginning of the `str1` string. When the `str1` string size will not change. If the length of the `str1` string can contain the entire `str2` string, the function will change `str1` to contain `str2` and then The letters of `str1` up to the original length of `str1`. In this case the function will return `1`. If the `str2` string is longer than `str1`, the first letters of `str2` will be placed in the `str1` string up to `str1`, In this case the function will return `0`.

Example 1:
`str1 = "abcdefgh" str2 = "xyz"`
After running the function:
`str1 = "xyzabcde"`
And the function will return `1`.

Example 2:
`str1 = "abcd" str2 = "efghj"`
After running the function:
`str1 = "efgh"`
And the function will return `0`

I started this one

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int string_pre(char *str1, char *str2) {
   int sizeStr1 = strlen(str1);
   int sizeStr2 = strlen(str2);
 
}

int main() {
   char str1[]= "abcdefgh";
   char str2[]= "xyz";

   string_pre(str1, str2);
   printf("After concatenation: %s %s \n", str1, str2);
   printf("After concatenation: %s \n", str2);
   return 0;
}
```

Not sure if this is the correct way to start.

Comment: It looks like a fine way to start.

Comment: Yepp. The only objection I have is that `strlen` doesn't return an `int`.

Comment: It's not concatentation, and I deleted an incorrect comment because of it. It's rearrangement.

Comment: The `strlen` function will do just fine determining the size of `str1`. The starting characters of `str1` should be moved right by the length of `str2` if possible. The number of characters moved is `strlen(str1) - strlen(str2)`. Then the characters of `str2` can be copied to the start of `str1`. It is possible to do this without any built-in functions, but it may be easiest to use `memmove`. Watch for corner cases based on particular string lengths.

Answer (score 1):

You have a good start. You might use `size_t` instead of `int` for the string lengths and define `str2` as `const char *str2` as it is not modified in the function so you can accept constant strings for this argument. Next should come a test if the length of `str1` is greater or equal to the length of `str2` and appropriate action should be taken in both cases.

Note that your `main` function should test multiple cases and print the return value too.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int string_pre(char *str1, const char *str2) {
    if (*str2 == '\0') {  // quick test for trivial case
        return 1;
    } else {
        size_t sizeStr1 = strlen(str1);
        size_t sizeStr2 = strlen(str2);
        if (sizeStr1 >= sizeStr2) {
            memmove(str1 + sizeStr2, str1, sizeStr1 - sizeStr2);
            memcpy(str1, str2, sizeStr2);
            return 1;
        } else {
            memcpy(str1, str2, sizeStr1);
            return 0;
        }
    }
}

int main() {
   char str1[]= "abcdefgh";
   char str2[]= "xyz";
   char str3[]= "xyzxyzxyzxyz";
   char str4[]= "ABCDEFGH";

   int n1 = string_pre(str1, str2);
   printf("test1:  n1=%d  str1='%s'  str2='%s'\n", n1, str1, str2);
   int n2 = string_pre(str1, str3);
   printf("test2:  n2=%d  str1='%s'  str3='%s'\n", n2, str1, str3);
   int n3 = string_pre(str1, str4);
   printf("test3:  n3=%d  str1='%s'  str4='%s'\n", n3, str1, str4);
   return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
test1:  n1=1  str1='xyzabcde'  str2='xyz'
test2:  n2=0  str1='xyzxyzxy'  str3='xyzxyzxyzxyz'
test3:  n3=1  str1='ABCDEFGH'  str4='ABCDEFGH'
```

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica: I'm afraid not because in all cases except `str2 = ""`, `str1` gets completely modified. I added a test for this corner case. Yet **O(sizeStr1)** is possible

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica: I had the same idea as the one you posted (check the source of my answer) but the beginning of `str1` must be shifted if `str2` is shorter than `str1`.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica: **O(sizeStr1)** is achieved if `sizeStr2` is computed as `sizeStr2 = strnlen(str2, sizeStr1 + 1);`

Comment: I do not find `strnlen()` in the standard C lib.  How about [`memchr()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72624072/2410359)?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica: `strnlen()` is POSIX but was rejected by the C Standard Committee, a ridiculous case of ultraconservatism given how many new functions are being added for new floating point type support... `memchr` could be used, but `memchr(str2, 0, sizeStr1)` is not fully defined in C99. An extra paragraph was added in C11 to fix the potential undefined behavior: *The implementation shall behave as if it reads the characters sequentially and stops as soon as a matching character is found.*  Furthermore, you need `memchr(str2, 0, sizeStr1+2)` to detect if `str2` is longer than `str1`.

Answer (score 0):

> Not sure if this is the correct way to start.

For starters neither declaration from the header `<stdlib.h>` is used in your program. So you may remove it.

The second function parameter must be declared with qualifier `const` because the corresponding string is not changed within the function.

```
int string_pre(char *str1, const char *str2);
```

The return type of the function `strlen` is `size_t`. So the variables `sizeStr1` and `sizeStr2` must be declared as having the type `size_t`.

```
size_t sizeStr1 = strlen(str1);
size_t sizeStr2 = strlen(str2);
```

Now all is ready to fill the body of the function with a code as for example :)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int string_pre( char *s1, const char *s2 )
{
    size_t n1 = strlen( s1 );
    size_t n2 = strlen( s2 );

    int moved_right = n2 < n1;

    if ( moved_right )
    {
        memmove( s1 + n2, s1, n1 - n2 );
    }
    else
    {
        n2 = n1;
    }

    memcpy( s1, s2, n2 );

    return moved_right;
}

int main( void )
{
    char s1[] = "abcdefgh";
    char s2[] = "xyz";

    int result = string_pre( s1, s2 );
    printf( "%d: %s\n", result, s1 );

    char s3[] = "abcd";
    char s4[] = "efghj";
    
    result = string_pre( s3, s4 );
    printf( "%d: %s\n", result, s3 );
}
```

The program output is

```
1: xyzabcde
0: efgh
```

If in case when the both strings are equal each other and you need to return 1 then in this case change this line

```
int moved_right = n2 < n1;
```

for example to this line

```
int moved_right = !( n1 < n2 );
```

Strictly speaking the function should be declared like

```
int string_pre(char * restrict str1, const char * restrict str2);
```

Comment: I'm afraid the return value is incorrect if `n1 == n2`: the function should return `1`

Comment: @chqrlie It is unclear. At first I also thought so and wrote the corresponding condition. But then I thought if the first string is fully overwritten then the function should return 0. But this is unimportant. The condition in any case can be changed if required.

Comment: The spec is somewhat confusing, but this point is unambiguous: *If the length of the `str1` string can contain the entire `str2` string...  the function will return 1, If the `str2` string is **longer** than `str1` ...  the function will return 0.*

Comment: @chqrlie As I wrote in fact it is unimportant. The condition can be changed in any moment if required.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the work.

however - using strlen to determine the length of a string buffer is normally a bad practice, as you may use buffers that are larger than the actual string they store. a more c way would be to pass on the length of buffer available.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int string_pre(char *str1,char *str2)
{

  size_t sizeStr1 = strlen(str1);
  size_t sizeStr2 = strlen(str2);

  long chars_to_move_right = sizeStr1 - sizeStr2;
  size_t chars_to_copy = sizeStr2 > sizeStr1 ? sizeStr1 : sizeStr2;

  // have to use memmove since the copying may overlap
  if (chars_to_move_right > 0)
  {
    memmove(str1 + sizeStr2, str1, chars_to_move_right);
  }
  
  // no overlap expected here, and memcpy may be more efficient.
  memcpy(str1, str2, chars_to_copy);
  return sizeStr1 >= sizeStr2;
}
int main()
{
    char str1[]= "abcdefgh";
    char str2[]= "xyz";
    

    printf("Before concatenation: '%s' '%s' \n",str1,str2);
    int res = string_pre(str1,str2);
    printf("After concatenation: '%s' '%s' \n",str1,str2);
    printf("Result = %d\n", res);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Code could be re-worked to not do a `size_t` subtraction when `sizeStr1 < sizeStr2` as that loses info with  truncating the difference to an `int`.

Comment: I'm afraid the return value is incorrect if `sizeStr1 == sizeStr2`: the function should return `1`

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica - fair point, but size_t is unsigned, so I can't do the subtraction, I switched to long, which is safe unless you insist to use giga sized strings.

Comment: @GalWeiss: `long` is not long enough on Windows, where strings can be longer than 2GB. You could use `ptrdiff_t`, but it is much simpler to test `if (sizeStr1 >= sizeStr2)`

Comment: No need for strcat in this function ??

Answer (score 0):

Rather than run the maximum length of both strings, how about iterating no more than the length of the first string?

```
int replace(char *str1, const char *str2) {
  size_t len1 = strlen(str1);
  // Search for the null character, but only so far.
  const char *end = memchr(str2, '\0', len1);
  size_t len2 = (end == NULL) ? len1 : end - str2;
  // At this point len2 <= len1

  memmove(str1 + len2, str1, len1 - len2); // Shift str1
  memmove(str1, str2, len2); // Copy in str2
  return str2[len2] == '\0'
}
```

Comment: Nice way to allow for `str1` and `str2` to point to the same string, but overlapping contents still cause undefined behavior if `str2 > str1`.

Comment: @chqrlie I do not see the UB when `str2 > str1`.  Details?

Comment: My bad, not UB, just unexpected result in case of overlapping contents with `str2 > str1`, because the end of `str2` is overwritten before `str2` is copied to `str1`.

Comment: @chqrlie, Perhaps, `int replace(char * restrict str1, const char * restrict str2)` to inform that user not to do that?

Comment: I guess so, and with these semantics (`str1` and `str2` must not overlap), the second call to `memmove` can be replaced with a `memcpy`.